# Python, PyInstaller error: no module named "Encodings" and system codec missing

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.3.3 and I have been trying to build a .exe from a simple .py script.

My script looks like this:

```
import encodings

print('Test')
```

and executes correctly.

When I try to build it with PyInstaller with this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile Testmodul.py`

and try to open my .exe it shows up with this error:
`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec, ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

I already tried importing the 'encodings' module in my testscript but it is still not working, I have also tried py2exe and it is also not working at all.

Is there anything I do wrong? Do I have to setup something in my PATH? the correct path to "C:\Python33" is included in there already.

EDIT: To everyone with this problem: I gave up, and after a fresh install of windows and python and all the other stuff, I tried it again, the same way as before and it worked without a problem.. It is worth a try if you are really desperate!

Comment: Did you have any idea `where is your SYS encoding data `, how to work python `encodings` ?  All OS details in Public usage ? Initialize mean `not registered` . This question related to your `python information level`. So a trick : this code work on idle cos granted a lot permissions and registered(non public) on more service/class . Initialize for which style `permanent/temporary` ?

Comment: Yes, i know `this is not low_level comment` !

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because pyinstaller did not include the module in the first place. Try one of the following solutions.

1) Specify the path to your module during compilation:

- pyinstaller --onefile --paths=/path/to/module Testscript.py

2) Specify the path from the .spec file:

- run this command first(in pyinstaller's directory):

  ```
  python Makespec.py --onefile /path/to/yourscript.py
  ```
- now you have the .spec file. open it in your text editor, and add the path to your modules to the pathex.

  ```
  pathex=['C:\\path\\to\\module']
  ```
- then, build your program:

  ```
   python Build.py /path/to/yourscript.spec
  ```

3) Use hidden imports:

- pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=modulename Testscript.py
- you can also specify hidden-import in the .spec file.

Comment: Or you could (from any directory if pyinstaller is in your path) run "pyinstaller /path/to/your.spec"

Comment: Eh, `encodings` is a Python standard library module... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Add hook file with name `hook-encodings.py` to `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks` location  and add following line of code to collect encodings module in hook file

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('encodings')
```

this may work,
this answer might help you [Pyinstaller Error for Djnago project "ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.apps'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342498/pyinstaller-error-for-djnago-project-importerror-no-module-named-django-contr)

Answer (score 0):

Which windows version are you using (7 or 10) ?

This issue seems to be relative to user privilege ... and assuming it is similar to [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue27054), you may first try to run your *exe* file with administrator privilege, and if it is failling again, try to run "Pyinstaller" from a *cmd.exe* running with administrator right.